# Can the Profile of "Christian" and "Christian Marinelli" be merged?

Tags: support, user-accounts

As per this [answer and below comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/62217/19334) the profiles of  "Christian" and "Christian Marinelli" seem to point to the same user.

As described in the comment this was due to forgetting the password of one the profiles.

I hope this is the right place to ask.

Comment: This happens regularly.  As goobering points out it's up to the user to pursue a merge but (as in this case) one of the accounts usually has only one post and <10 rep so it isn't worth caring about.

Comment: @goldilocks I posted this, not because I wanted to report some kind infringement, but because the user mentioned it like it was unintentional and something he hinted he wanted to change if possible.

Comment: I guess it's an issue if you create an account, ask a question, then realise because you can't log in as the original user, your second 1 rep account can't reply to comments on the first account's question.  It would be useful if mods had the power to do the merge for that purpose at least under certain circumstances, to save everyone some time and hassle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for posting. I've messaged the user in question regarding their accounts, but it's really their call whether they'd like to merge them or not. As detailed in [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts), there isn't a hard site policy on multiple accounts - you're free to do so provided you don't use them to upvote each other or otherwise manipulate the reputation system. If a user does choose to merge multiple accounts the recommended procedure is detailed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) on the Meta help pages:

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please
>   sign into either account, visit the contact form and select ‘I need to
>   merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team
>   will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm
>   your ownership, we will initiate a merge.